# Is there a difference between .get() and -> with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, operators, smart-pointers

Do `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`s function `.get()` and the `operator->` do exactly the same?

Or is there a difference as with `std::vector`s `.at()` and `operator[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The have identical behaviour (in both cases `operator->()` is defined to return `get()`), but `operator->()` has the precondition that `get()` must not return 0.

This means that:

```
a.get();        // does not cause UB just because holds a null pointer
a.operator->(); // would cause UB if a.get() == 0
```

where `a` is either a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr`.